# How to make Django Nested Templates for better SRP

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I'm attempting to make a base template for my website. Ideally it would look like this

```
{% block navigationbar %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% endblock %}
```

This way I am able to have separate navigationbar.html and footer.html files. All views I would like to show would then just put this:

```
{% extends 'portfolio/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
// View Code here
{% endblock %}
```

Any way to achieve this. I have realized I can't do multiple extends and I've tried different combinations of nesting but nothing has worked for me so far.

So the ideal result would be 4 files. for the homepage:

1. NavigationBar.html - Holds the navigation bar code
2. Footer.html - Holds the footer code
3. Base.html - Holds the navigation bar, footer, and content
4. Home.html - Holds the content of the home page, but when it loads the user sees the navigationbar, and footer as well.

Comment: You can extend an extended view, and thus construct a *hierarchy*. But it is not clear to me exactly what you aim to achieve.

Comment: Updated the question. Basically I want a base file to just be the layout of nav, content, footer. Then I want the code for those components to exist in separate files.

Comment: you can use `{% include ... %}` to render subfiles.

Comment: Wow awesome that worked. I just changed the nav and footer to include. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) that loads a template and renders it with the current context. This is a way of “including” other templates within a template.

This example includes the contents of the template "NavigationBar.html" and "Footer.html" on your template:

```
{% extends 'portfolio/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "NavigationBar.html" %}

    // View Code here

    {% include "Footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

You can also pass additional context to the template using arguments:

```
{% include "NavigationBar.html" with breadcrumb="home > wherever" %}
```